# Why does the the sprite image only appear if I assign the property display to the CSS declaration?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have the following code

```
a.rollover {
        background-image: url('sprite.jpg');
        display: block;
        width: 191px;
        height: 143px;
    }
```

However it only appears if I include the property `display` and set it to `block`. If I remove it, it does not appear. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a>` are `display:inline` by default, and width/height aren't applied to inline elements. You can use `display:inline-block` to allow for sizing and still keep it inline.